# How to find the ground energy state solution in a quantum harmonic oscillator?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, quantum-mechanics

Recently, I came across a question which asks to solve the Schrödinger equation for a harmonic oscillator on $ [a, b] $ :

$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{d x^2} + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 x^2 \psi = E \psi$

I can use the 'shooting method' to find $ E $ for which the BVP $ \psi(a) = 0 $ and $\psi(b) = 0 $ has a solution. This can be done by using the Numerov algorithm to find $ \psi $ at $ x = b $ starting from $ \psi(a) = 0 $ and $ \psi(a+\delta x) = c $ where $ c $ is an arbitrary constant, and then varying the parameter $E$ by the secant method until the BVP is solved.  But, in addition, what if I also want to ensure that the final $E$ value will be the ground state energy level of the oscillator ?

One method would be to pick up an initial guess of $ E $ very close to the ground energy, so that the shooting method iterations converge to the ground energy level, but that would require *a priori* guessing of the same.

Another problem is, even if the ground state is found, how do I know that the solution is really the ground state solution ? *Note that the ground state is defined to be the minimum allowed energy state of a particle in a given potential field.*

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you requiring an exact solution to compare a numerical solution to?

Comment: @Dan No, I want a complete numerical solution.

Comment: Ok I was just wondering

Comment: One way to identify the ground state wavefunction is that it should have no nodes i.e. $|\psi(x)|>0$ (except as required by boundary conditions). If memory serves, one moreover can show that $\psi(x)$ can be taken to be purely real in this context, and therefore conclude that the ground-state wavefunction is everywhere positive. So if the result you get satisfies this, you're done.